# Sharepoint 2019 on-prem - Quick Chart

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, sharepoint-list, chart

I want to add a quick chart with SharePoint List data but I do not see the option "Get data from a SharePoint list on this site". Why?

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function doesn't exist in SharePoint Server 2019. SharePoint Server 2019 is a one-time fork of SharePoint Online before the 'list data' option was available.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to create a chart based on a SharePoint list in Team site {modern}? I know in Team site (classic experience) there is a webpart ChartWebPart. I cannot implement this chart in Team site {modern}.

Comment: I'm not aware of any modern webparts that have this functionality. You'll probably have to look for a 3rd party solution or build one.

Comment: Here's a third party solution for charts on Modern pages: https://www.365automate.com/charts